# Unable to Run Android Studio on windows 10

Tags: android, android-studio, windows-10, android-sdk-tools

I am facing very weird problem since I Installed Android Studio on Windows 10 N.

After complete Installation of Android Studio It's hang on Splash Screen.

I solved that issue by adding `disable.android.first.run=true` to tail of the idea.properties file and it worked but after that ON creating new project It says to Configure SDK path in Project Structure which I did correctly.

But after that I am unable to make any new project, see SDK manager

The path of java is also set correctly and I test it by running a Test Program

If anybody had face same Issue Please help

Thank you all for suggestions in advance

My Laptop Configuration is i5 6th Gen, 4 GB RAM , 1 TB HDD, 2 GB Graphic card.

Comment: This is just a suggestion - i had issues in W10 with the Android Studio components (SDK included) when trying to put them into the folders with the spaces in name. Placing all of them into the c:\Programs\ folder (just a folder created) worked for me. And installing and launching all of them in the administrator mode also worked for some issues.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion.
I will try this

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally I make it with the help of the @Alex Belotserkovskiy Useful comment.

What I did :-

1) Formatted my Laptop because its a fresh machine.

2) Installed JDK Version greater than 1.8 as it was suggested on [this](https://developer.android.com/sdk/installing/index.html)

link.

3) Set java path

4) Download the latest Version of Android Studio from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html)

I downloaded the one with SDK and System Image

5) While installing Android Studio ,Run setup by right click and select Run as Administrator

6) While Installing make sure that when setup ask for path of Android Studio and SDK the path should not contains any White Spaces

7) Your are good to go.

8) If face any Issue like hang up of AS on Splash Screen follow my step from question.

Comment: i added disable.android.first.run=true and it's working fine

Comment: Where do you make this change?